# Malicious site using "stackoverflow.com" as subdomain

Tags: support, copycat-sites

I am not sure if this is the right place to post this but I am unaware
 of any other stack to get such issue into notice.

I came across this site today from google search http://stackoverflow.com.mevn.net/ Which mirrors SO site. Thought its better to get this into the SO team's notice.

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360030/4284627)

Comment: No need to panic. That's not the first and not the last site to copy and mirror SO illegally. There are hundreds of those.

Comment: Ya this is the exact duplicate of the marked question. Surprisingly this site appears on google first page.

Comment: No surprise, if the contents is exactly the same, Google can't really know it's not legit.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard true that. But isn't there anything that can be done on such sites?

Comment: By us? Only report to Google. To shut down those sites SE has to use layers, spend time and money, and I'm not sure it's worth all that hassle. But it's not in our hands. Edit: turns out Google has no way to report scrapers, they had for short time and decided to nuke it. Makes sense, it's not really their problem, and Google has no reason to spend even one cent on this, they are big enough to not care about their customers.

Comment: I get it. I am just curious on how they do these things in spite of cross origin block and SO having the feature to detect bots..

Comment: What does such a malicious site do?