# What is the minimum reputation amount required to view questions without replies tagged as "duplicate""?

Tags: support, reputation, duplicate-questions, login

When not logged in, attempting to visit a question that is marked as duplicate of another and doesn't have any replies, redirects to the original question (i.e. the question displayed in the "possible duplicates" banner.)

Example: When not logged in, visiting this question [Malicious site using "stackoverflow.com" as subdomain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305443/malicious-site-using-stackoverflow-com-as-subdomain) redirects to [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do). When I am logged in using this account (477 reputation) this redirect doesn't happen.

What is the minimum reputation amount required to view duplicate questions without redirecting?

Comment: Note that anonymous visitors can still view the duplicate question by appending `?noredirect=1` to the URL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The minimum reputation is 1. You just need to have an account and be logged in for the redirect not to be applied; it only applies to [anonymous (logged-out) users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125807/295232):

> Starting with the next build, anonymous users will be redirected when they visit duplicate questions with no answers.
>
> As with migration and merge redirects you can disable with `?noredirect=1`.